# ERROR to impute and fix the missing value in Spider IDE

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am new in Machine Learning, I am trying to fix the missing data of a dataset in [Spyder IDE](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) so I want to use [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) library in python of scikit-learn. So I am getting an error over here that `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`.

```
# IMPORTING THE LIBRARY
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd




# IMPORTING THE DATASET
dataset = pd.read_csv('file:///C:/Users/Bhaskar Das/Desktop/Udemy/Machine_Learning_AZ_Template_Folder/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 1 - Data Preprocessing/Section 2 -------------------- Part 1 - Data Preprocessing --------------------/Data.csv')

x = dataset.iloc[:,:].values
# =============================================================================
# Out[4]: 
#    Country   Age   Salary Purchased
# 0   France  44.0  72000.0        No
# 1    Spain  27.0  48000.0       Yes
# 2  Germany  30.0  54000.0        No
# 3    Spain  38.0  61000.0        No
# 4  Germany  40.0      NaN       Yes
# 5   France  35.0  58000.0       Yes
# 6    Spain   NaN  52000.0        No
# 7   France  48.0  79000.0       Yes
# 8  Germany  50.0  83000.0        No
# 9   France  37.0  67000.0       Yes
# =============================================================================

# TAKING CARE OF MISSING DATA
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = '0')
imputer = imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])
x[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(x[:, 1:3])
```

I am showing the exact code line which is generating the below error given in the output.

**Line from the above code which is throwing the error.**

```
imputer = imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
runfile('C:/Users/Bhaskar Das/.spyder-py3/DataPreprocessing-ML.py', wdir='C:/Users/Bhaskar Das/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-2ed93817316a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Bhaskar Das/.spyder-py3/DataPreprocessing-ML.py', wdir='C:/Users/Bhaskar Das/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\Bhaskar Das\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Bhaskar Das\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Bhaskar Das/.spyder-py3/DataPreprocessing-ML.py", line 142, in <module>
    imputer = imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])

  File "C:\Users\Bhaskar Das\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Users\Bhaskar Das\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Users\Bhaskar Das\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1840, in _get_item_cache
    res = cache.get(item)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `x` is a pandas DataFrame with column labels. As a result, the syntax you use,

```
x[:, 1:3]
```

is invalid for slicing along the column dimension, and this is what generates the error message.

So somewhere there is another bug or you have not shown the exact code you are using, since otherwise the operation

```
x = dataset.iloc[:,:].values
```

should return a numpy ndarray that would not result in this error message.

This is corroborated by the traceback you showed in your question, which says:

```
File "C:/Users/Bhaskar Das/.spyder-py3/DataPreprocessing-ML.py", line 142, in <module>
    imputer = imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])

  File "C:\Users\Bhaskar Das\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
```

among other things. The object being sliced inside the `imputer` call is definitely a pandas DataFrame, which means the code pasted in the question is likely missing something from your actual code.

Note also that you can simply fill in the missing value directly with pandas:

```
dataset.fillna(
    {'Age': dataset.Age.mean(), 'Salary': dataset.Salary.mean()},
    inplace=True
)
```

Comment: Is it? But the error is coming exactly in this line `imputer = imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])` and `iloc` is not creating any issue.

Comment: @BhaskarDas You can even seen in your traceback that you posted to the question, the error occurs in pandas\core\frame.py. So I suspect the code you showed us is not the real code, because the value `x` being passed to the imputer is definitely a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: @BhaskarDas Also note that your tracebacks tell us it happens on line 142 of a file called `DataPreprocessing-ML.py` .. so it can't be true that your original question is pasting over the *exact* code. Likely there is some mistake in what you are pasting that would mean the variable back in the other file is remaining as a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: The line I have shown that lies in line number 142 and `DataPreprocessing-ML.py` is the file name. Where is my mistake? I couldn't understand how to fix. It is showing everything is fine but the error is throwing by that line `imputer = imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])`

Answer (score 1):

Why oh why do people insist on making their lives more difficult by extracting arrays from dataframes? sklearn plays well with pandas!!

Once you solve the error that @ely has shown, another error is because you are writing:

`imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = '0')`

when I think you mean to write:

`imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)`

In the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html), it says:

> axis : **integer**, optional (default=0)
>
> The axis along which to impute.
>
> If axis=0, then impute along columns. If axis=1, then impute along
>   rows.

Comment: Good catch. But unfortunately, this will not throw the error shown by the OP. The OP is doing something in between which is changing the `x` to dataframe from an array as @ely has spotted.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar. Yeah, I realised after posting that ely's issue is the one causing the posted error (made an small edit).

Answer (score 0):

your cold should be right expect for '0'should  be 0. I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import imputation
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='Nan', strategy='mean', axis=0)
imputer= imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])
x[:, 1:3]=imputer.transform(x[:, 1:3])
```

> C:\Users\Pravesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:66: DeprecationWarning: Class Imputer is deprecated; Imputer was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. Import impute.SimpleImputer from sklearn instead.
>     warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 3, in 
>       imputer= imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])
>
> File "C:\Users\Pravesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in **getitem**
>      indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
>
> File "C:\Users\Pravesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>
> TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), slice(1, 3, None))' is an invalid key

I am getting this as an error while using the same code